# Unable to free C pointer

Tags: c, macos, malloc, free

I have been learning C for the last few weeks in Linux Mint.
But, I switched to OSX and was testing this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  int *arr = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
  if(arr == NULL)
    printf("arr is null");

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++, arr++){
    printf("%d \n", *arr);
  }


  free(arr);

  return 0;

}
```

This should work and print 10 zeros, which it does but it does not free arr.

This is the output:

```
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
a.out(532,0x7fff72606300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff060c04b48: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I don't understand how I could access memory that was not allocated. Shouldn't the output be "arr is null" if arr is not allocated?

Comment: What is the value of `arr` when you pass it to `free`?

Comment: You can avoid the problem by using array syntax, e.g. `printf("%d\n",arr[i]);` That way, you don't need the `arr++` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program increments `arr` ten times. The pointer that you're passing to `free` isn't the same one that you received from `calloc`. You need to pass the original address, pre-incrementing.

Comment: Oh! I had the printing in a different function which also used arr to reference the pointer to an array. Then, I moved it into main which caused the problem. Thanks so much!